# creating records from automated action in odoo11

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I want to create an automated action where I could create multiple records for a model.

How can I refer to a particular user id from res.partner?

I can create simple records using

```py
env['project.task'].create({'name': 'some_name', 'deadline': 'date' })
```

I also need to assign a few fields like assigned to and assigned by which have a relation as many2one with res.partner model.

How can I add these relation values and access particular id from the res.partner model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add many2one fields by passing their id in the dict.

```
user_id = self.env['res_users'].search([('name', '=', '*User Name*')]).id
```

Make sure you have **only one user** with that name or use field **login** or any as per your requirement.

Then create your report

```
self.env['project.task'].create({
    'name': 'Some Name',
    'user_id': user_id
})
```

Comment: you forgot a comma i guess :P

Comment: Sorry. Updated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary and pass the dictionary to the create method.

```
res = {
 'name':'XYZ'
 'deadline':'25-7-2019'
}
abc = self.env['project.task'].create(res)
```